# Switch between JSON (Jackson processor) and XML (XStream) or can i use it simultaneously?

Tags: xml, json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm trying to build an Web-Server which can serialize an Object into JSON and XML. Since I've integrated Jackson (using an example-Project) I'm able to access an JSON-Serialized Object via my REST Interface, but i'd like to get XML too.

this...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main/ajax")
public class AjaxController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/blah", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml")
public @ResponseBody List<String> blah(@RequestParam(value="input") String input){

            List<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
            stringList.add("i");
            stringList.add("am");
            stringList.add("an");
            stringList.add("json object");
            stringList.add(input);

            return stringList;
    }
 }
```

whit this query:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-json/krams/main/ajax/blah?input=foobar
```

produces that output:

```
["i","am","an","json object","foobar"]
```

Any hints?

UPDATE #1: I implemented the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver...

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />

  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
      <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </map>
  </property>

  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>

      <!-- JSON View -->
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

      <!-- XML View --> 
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
         <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>  

    </list>
  </property>

  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- If no extension matched, use JSP view -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="2" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

How do i now select either XML or JSON?
        localhost:8080/spring-json/sometestclass/status  ?
        localhost:8080/spring-json/sometestclass/status.xml  ?
        localhost:8080/spring-json/sometestclass/status.json ?

None of the examples above are working, but i can force the response-format with the Accept-header "application/xml" or "application/json" ... if i do the following...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody Web_ServerStatus isServerAlive() {
    Web_ServerStatus l_ReturnObj = new Web_ServerStatus();
```

...i only get XML back.

What's the problem i am running into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might want to reword question a bit; a JSON interfaces can be REST interfaces too... so perhaps you mean an XML interface vs JSON interface instead?

Comment: You are right StaxMan, thanks! -> edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Web_ServerStatus isServerAlive() {
  ...
}
```

WITHOUT "@ResponseBody"

Comment: Ok, good. I did not notice that you had, but it makes sense. A @ResponseBody annotation indicates that the response should bypass view resolution. So, can you switch representations based on suffix now?

Comment: Yes, and with "<property name="defaultContentType" value="application/xml"/>" i get XML back by default, but i can switch to JSON, if i append ".json".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at ContentNegotiatingViewResolver (since you included spring as a tag).

Here's a link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations.

But, REST does not imply XML. Depending on the client's Accept header and the capabilities of you service, you can render the resource in different ways.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer... but i dont want tu use any kind of accept-headers. i'd like to force the response to a specific output-type like JSON/XML and read something about a dot-notation like .xml .json an so on... or better:
by default my server returns XML, but if i add ".json" to the URI, it returns JSON ... is that possible?